# How to store an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need help about an exercise. It says I have to create a little program in PHP which creates 7 random numbers (actually it's a lottery with 6 random numbers and 1 random number (complementary) between 1 and 49). That numbers have to store in an array. 
The problem is I must to store that numbers in a file too. I did this:

```
$num[1]=rand(1,49);
$num[2]=rand(1,49);
$num[3]=rand(1,49);
$num[4]=rand(1,49);
$num[5]=rand(1,49);
$num[6]=rand(1,49);
$num[7]=rand(1,49);
echo "The numbers are: "; echo $num[1]; echo "-"; echo $num[2]; echo "-"; echo $num[3]; echo "-"; echo $num[4]; echo "-"; echo $num[5]; echo "-"; echo $num[6];
echo "<br>";
echo "Complementary: ".$num[7];
```

Then I tried something like this to store that numbers:

```
$lott=array($num[1],$num[2],$num[3],$num[4],$num[5],$num[6]);
$comp=array($num[7]);
$arch=fopen("lottery.txt","a") or die("Internal error");
fputs($arch,"Lottery numbers:");
fputs($arch,$_REQUEST['lott']);
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch, "Complementary number:");
fputs($arch,$_REQUEST['comp']);
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch,"-------------------------------------------------------");
fputs($arch,"\n");
fclose($arch);
echo "The dates have been stored correctly.";
```

Obviously it doesn't work. I'm new with php, so I don't know how to store that numbers in a file.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: *Obviously it doesn't work* - What doesn't work? What happens instead? Is there an error message?

Comment: and where's this coming from? `$_REQUEST['lott']`

Comment: `or die("Internal error")` get the real error, should there be one. Use error reporting.

Comment: @ilos28:  It might be a good idea to follow tutorials before trying exercises that will merely show that you don't know how to do it.  `serialized()` and `unserialize()` seem an appropriate solution to export and import an array.

Comment: The numbers are not stored in the file. When I open that code with firefox it says that it has a problem with this line "$_REQUEST['lott']" and "$_REQUEST['comp']". So I supposed that it was because of the arrays.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and var_dump(), what do we get?

Comment: This exercise was from an exam. My teacher said that we had to do it. But we don't know about arrays so much, so it was his fault.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual for `$_REQUEST`? It doesn't look like you are using that correctly.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier: I used the only knowledge about php that my professor taught us. And he said we have to do it in the exam. So I wanted to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save `$_REQUEST['lott']` and `$_REQUEST['comp']` to your file. Are these variables set?

Just save your `$lott` and `$comp` variables. Both are arrays and therefor must be converted to string, before you can save it. You can use `implode()` for this.

```
$lott=array($num[1],$num[2],$num[3],$num[4],$num[5],$num[6]);
$comp=array($num[7]);
$arch=fopen("lottery.txt","a") or die("Internal error");
fputs($arch,"Lottery numbers:");
fputs($arch,implode(',', $lott));
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch, "Complementary number:");
fputs($arch,implode(',', $comp));
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch,"-------------------------------------------------------");
fputs($arch,"\n");
fclose($arch);
```

This will output

```
Lottery numbers:37,27,41,1,2,14

Complementary number:19
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I didn't know about "implode()". It was very useful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function implode to join your array data in one string:

```
$lott=array($num[1],$num[2],$num[3],$num[4],$num[5],$num[6]);
$comp=array($num[7]);
$arch=fopen("lottery.txt","a") or die("Internal error");
fputs($arch,"Lottery numbers:");
fputs($arch, implode(' - ', $lott); //HERE
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch, "Complementary number:");
fputs($arch,$comp[0]); //HERE you get only index 0, because your array have just one item
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch,"-------------------------------------------------------");
fputs($arch,"\n");
fclose($arch);
echo "The dates have been stored correctly.";
```

Comment: Ok. If I want to store an array with one item I always have to use "0" like index. So, why it doesn't work when you tried something like: "fputs($arch,$lott[6])"?

Comment: In arrays, you start counting with "0", not "1". In this case, there is no index 6 in $lott, the last one is 5 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) -> 6 elements.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I always forgot about "0". Well, this example is very useful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is to your answer: The code is commented though---

```
    <?php

        // GENERATE 6 RANDOM NUMBERS BETWEEN 1 AND 49 WITH...       
        $arrRandNumbers = array();

        for($i=1; $i<7; $i++){
            $arrRandNumbers[]   = rand(1, 49);
        }

        // BUILD-UP A STRING FOR THE RANDOM NUMBERS, DELIMITED WITH A NEW LINE CHARACTER
        $strRandom      = "";
        foreach($arrRandNumbers as $randNumber){
            $strRandom .= $randNumber . "\n";
        }

        // STORE NUMBER IN A TEXT FILE... FILE-NAME: random-numbers.txt
        file_put_contents("random-numbers.txt", rtrim($strRandom, "\n"));

        var_dump($arrRandNumbers);
```

And here is another Variant:

```
    <?php

        // GENERATE 6 RANDOM NUMBERS BETWEEN 1 AND 49 WITH...
        $arrRandNumbers = array();

        for($i=1; $i<7; $i++){
            $arrRandNumbers[]   = rand(1, 49);
        }

        // GENERATE A COMPLEMENTARY NUMBER: BETWEEN 1 AND 49 WITH...
        $compNum        = rand(1, 49);

        // BUILD-UP A STRING FOR THE RANDOM NUMBERS, DELIMITED WITH 2 SPACES & WRAPPED IN SQUARE BRACKETS
        $strRandom      = "LOTTERY NUMBERS:" .PHP_EOL;
        foreach($arrRandNumbers as $randNumber){
            $strRandom .= "[" . $randNumber . "]  ";
        }

        // TRIM-OFF THE SPACES TO THE RIGHT OF THE LOTTERY NUMBERS:
        rtrim($strRandom);


        // ADD THE COMPLEMENTARY NUMBER TO THE MIX WITH 3 NEW LINES IN-BETWEEN:
        $strRandom     .= "\n\n\nCOMPLEMENTARY NUMBER:\n" . $compNum;

        // STORE NUMBER IN A TEXT FILE... FILE-NAME: random-numbers.txt
        file_put_contents("random-numbers.txt", $strRandom);

        var_dump($arrRandNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$num[1]=rand(1,49);
$num[2]=rand(1,49);
$num[3]=rand(1,49);
$num[4]=rand(1,49);
$num[5]=rand(1,49);
$num[6]=rand(1,49);
$num[7]=rand(1,49);
echo "The numbers are: "; echo $num[1]; echo "-"; echo $num[2]; echo "-"; echo $num[3]; echo "-"; echo $num[4]; echo "-"; echo $num[5]; echo "-"; echo $num[6];
echo "<br>";
echo "Complementary: ".$num[7];

$lott=array($num[1],$num[2],$num[3],$num[4],$num[5],$num[6]);
$comp=array($num[7]); // You don't need an array to store only one number
$arch=fopen("lottery.txt","a") or die("Internal error");
fputs($arch,"Lottery numbers:");
//fputs($arch,$_REQUEST['lott']);
foreach ($lott as $number)
{
    fputs($arch, $number);
    fputs($arch, "\n");
}
fputs($arch, "Complementary number:");
//fputs($arch,$_REQUEST['comp']);
fputs($arch, $comp[0]);
fputs($arch,"\n");
fputs($arch,"-------------------------------------------------------");
fputs($arch,"\n");
fclose($arch);
echo "The dates have been stored correctly.";
```